# jquery ajax navigaion inside wordpress content area

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

this is a completely noob question, but i am at a loss at this moment.
I have been trying to find a solution to this problem but i cannot seem to find a definitive answer only snippets from here and there.

i am looking to create a left hand side menu on a standard wordpress page.
the menu consists of titles of  specific wordpress posts within the website its self. when you click on one of the titles, the content of that post is shown in a div container on the same page as the title .

How would i go about achieving this?

Now i know there're alot of tutorials on similar ideas, but my problem is that i am having a hard time trying to piece together all the elements to come up with one solution. for instance,

how do i go about getting the ajax to call the specific posts? do i have to call the get_post function?

how do i go about setting the titles to then correspond to the specific posts?

how do i implementing all of the above on the wordpress page?

Again i know this is a noob question but i would be really greatful if any one had any information, tutorial or source code that i could look at so as to learn and implement within my page.

[image: See Figure]

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to automate what is shown in the sidebar. I am not familiar with Wordpress, but you could certainly do this manually with something like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which always has great UI solutions.

You can always use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to show/hide content that the user clicked on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#toggle").click(function(){
    $("div#t1").toggle();
  });
  $("#toggle2").click(function(){
    $("div#t2").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="t1">#1</div>
<div id="t2">Stuff</div>
<button id="toggle1">Content 1</button>
<button id="toggle2">Content 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can just incorporate this into your format.

Comment: You can use this kind of idea: <a href="http://api.jquery.com/toggle/">http://api.jquery.com/toggle/</a>, <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp">http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp</a> and <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show">http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show</a>.

Comment: unfortunately my problem is wordpress specific :( i really do need some how to get that post data on to my page via the links , im going to have to carry on hunting